# rsnapshot a remote server - best practice for permissions

Tags: rsnapshot

I am trying to setup ssh-key based login for a remote server to rsnapshot daily. The key I am using is a normal user key, but it obviously doesn't have root access, so when rsnapshot connects to the server with the user key, /root for example won't be backed up. What is the best way to setup rsnapshot in the simplest possible way? Should I just create a normal backup user, and add it to the wheel group and be done with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perhaps not so simple way is to connect as `root` but to limit the key used to connect to only run specific invocations of `rsync`; this requires an `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` entry along the lines of

```
 from="192.0.2.*",command="/root/limit-rsnap" ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...
```

which limits both where the backup is expected to originate from (this may not be ideal for all setups) and more importantly in the `/root/limit-rsnap` script on the system being connected to only specific calls to `rsync` are allowed:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

test -n "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" || exit 1

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
  'rsync --server --sender -'+([vnlHogDtprRxe.isfLS])' --numeric-ids . '*)
    RSYNCPATH="${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND#rsync --server --sender -+([vnlHogDtprRxe.isfLS]) --numeric-ids . }"
    test -e "$RSYNCPATH" && exec $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND || exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    exit 1
  ;;
esac
```